# Negate a predicate Proc in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a Proc, which is predicate.

```
Proc.new { |number| number.even? }
```

Is there a way to somehow create another Proc which have the opposite meaning? I can't change the "body" of the Proc, because the Proc will come as function parameter. So I want something like this:

```
not(Proc.new { |number| number.even? }
# which of course doesn't work :(
```

and I want it to do the same as

```
Proc.new { |number| number.odd? }
```

The idea is that I want a function similar to this:

```
def negate(proc)
  negated proc with meaning opposite of this of proc
end
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It is not clear to me..Probably you are trying to negate the result of the proc ..right?

Comment: Yes, I think it will do the job.

Comment: See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dinesman%27s_multiple-dwelling_problem#By_parsing_the_problem for a working example (22nd line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following method returns the procedure opposite to the provided one.

```
def negate(procedure)
  Proc.new { |*args| !procedure.call(*args) }
end
```

or, using shorter notation:

```
def negate(procedure)
  proc { |*args| !procedure.call(*args) }
end
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit I don't "change body" of provided procedure here. I take it as an argument and return another procedure that behave in "opposite" manner.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help at all?

```
p = Proc.new { |number| number.even? }
p.call(1) #=> false
!p.call(1) #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more functional-programming-like (albeit possibly more cryptic) approach, you can utilise two Ruby facts:

- [`!` is a regular method defined on Ruby objects](https://metaredux.com/posts/2019/05/05/weird-ruby-pure-object-oriented-negation.html)
- you can compose procs in Ruby with `>>` and `<<`

```rb
is_odd = proc { |n| n % 2 == 1 }
is_even = is_odd >> :!.to_proc

p is_even.call(3) # => false

# Or, extracting into a utility
negate = :!.to_proc
is_even = negate << is_odd # or is_odd >> negate

p is_even.call(3) # => false
```

Voila! Maybe not the most obvious, but a bit of fun.